# In Git, after merging back and forth, why aren't the branches at the same point?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

We have been doing a project with Git according to what I understand to be a pretty standard branching model, described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

We have started with "master" and branched "develop" from it. There were lots of commits to "develop", and then we branched "release-1" from "develop". There were some commits to "release-1", then we merged "release-1" to "master", and again merged "release-1" to "develop". Then we deleted "release-1".

Now I would expect "master" and "develop" branches to be at the same point. And they do have the same files, but according to branch graph they have completely different histories, with the only common point being the very first commit in the repository.

So two questions:

1) Why don't they have the same history / why aren't they at the same point?

2) How can we fix it? Should we force merge "develop" to "master" or "master" to "develop"?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the git commit history that you have?  Sounds like the process you went through is the correct one, but perhaps it is just a misinterpretation of the current state.

Comment: Post the output of  `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`

Comment: As you clearly have experienced, GitFlow is not intuitive, and mostly results in confusion down the line. Have a look at https://kofoedanders.com/git-cooperation-simplified/ or http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful for a a closer look at what you should do instead.

Comment: @sp1nakr Interesting. I'll have to read it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As LeGec says, a commit is generated from a various information including the [author, committer, parent commit, and more](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865) that should make it unique/identifieable.

From your description it sounds like this is your situation:

```
Master  | M1 -------------------------> M2 (merge commit)
--------    \                          /
Release |    \                R1 -> R2
--------      \              /         \ 
Develop |      D1 -> D2 -> D3 --------> D4 (merge commit)
```

As you've described in your case, the files within M2 and D4 will be the same, however their parent commits, and the time at which they were created, will be different.

That is unlikely to cause you issues as your work will continue on `develop` and you can happily follow the release workflow next time. Since you aren't committing on `master` independently, you shouldn't run into merge conflicts.

If you wished to "fix it", that is give them a common commit, you could merge `master` into `develop`, but it won't really gain you anything except an additional merge commit.

```
Master  | M1 -------------------------> M2 (merge commit)
--------    \                          /   \ 
Release |    \                R1 -> R2      \
--------      \              /         \     \
Develop |      D1 -> D2 -> D3 --------> D4 -> D5 (merge commit)
```

Note, this is assuming you are not performing fast forward merges.

Comment: I see. However, my main problem is that when we create a new release branch from "develop" and then a pull request from the release branch to "master", the "diff" of the pull request will show all the files from "develop", and not just the new ones since the last release. (At least this is how Atlassian Stash behaves). Would merging "master" to "develop" solve this?

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying if you're creating a subsequent release branch, e.g. from a new commit on `develop`, `D6`, when it comes time to create the pull `R3` -> `Master`, the pull request is showing the changes from `D1`..`D3` as well? That's not what I'd expect =o

Comment: If we take your first diagram (with M2 and D4 as the last commits), create a release branch from D4 and create a pull request from that release branch to master, Atlassian Stash is showing all changes from D1 to D4 in that pull request, while comparing release to master in Tortoise Git shows no changes (as I would expect). So that might be a Stash issue. :/

Comment: That's very strange, has the M1 -> M2 merge happened on the server? Are you comparing the server branches via Tortoise Git (rather than just local)? Like yourself I would expect no changes to be shown in the diff.

Comment: You mean R2 -> M2 merge? Yes, there is a commit "Merge pull request [...] from release[...] to master" on the server. There's just no line connecting develop with master in the branch diagram because the release branch was deleted.
I'm comparing "remote" branches via Tortoise Git.

Comment: How strange, I  would be inclined to run `git log remote/master..remote/develop` to see a list of the changes `develop` has that `master` doesn't have, I would expect to see only the release-> develop merge commit. It may indeed be something about stash I'm not familiar with =o

Answer (score 2):

It is normal behavior for git to create different commits on different actions :

A commit keeps track of a bunch of information : its parents, its author, its creation date, its committer and last commit date.

If any of these informations are different, git will create two distinct commits.

For example : when merging `release-1` into `master`, and then `release-1` into `develop`

- if the starting point for `master` and `develop` was not the exact same commit, the two merge commits will not have the same parents ;
- unless you run both commands at the speed of light, they will not have the same timestamp.

---

The content of the files in a commit is called its `tree`.

git also keeps a hash of the content of a commit, which you can view using :

```
git rev-parse master^{tree}
git rev-parse develop^{tree}
```

You can confirm that the two commits have the exact same contents by looking at their tree hashes.

---

If you want to have `develop` and `master` point at the same commit, you can hard set `develop` to `master` :

```
git branch -f develop master
```

In your merging process, you could have reached the same state by :

1. merging `release-1` into `master`
2. tell git to "fast forward" `develop` to `master` :

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git merge --ff-only master
   ```

   with `git merge --ff-only` :

   - git will first check if `master's` history contains the full history of develop,
   - if it does, it will move `develop` to `master` (instead of creating a new commit),
   - otherwise, it will print a warning and leave `develop` unmodified.